# Imagick CLI not converting base64 images in SVG to PNG

Tags: svg, base64, imagick

Using the Imagick CLI with the example SVG document coded below, the images do not render in the png, however if convert the SVG to an html document it all loads. I can decode the base64 online and it shows the valid image, and tried different Image tag notation. I am lost at what I am doing wrong.

```
magick .\test.svg image.png
```

- ImageMagick 7.1.0-49 Q16-HDRI x64 7a3f3f1:20220924
- Windows 10 OS

Example Code that is not Rendering:

```
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;" version="1.1" id="natal_chart" width="800" height="800" viewBox="0 0 800 800">

<image x='322' y='402' preserveAspectRatio='none' href='data:image/png;base64,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'></image>
<img src='data:image/png;base64,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'/>

</svg>
```

Comment: img is not a valid SVG element and I bet ImageMagick wants height and width attributes on the image element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the above code as a standalone SVG file that you feed to ImageMagick, you need to do several things:

1. Use a default namespace: `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` in addition to the `xlink` namespace declaration
2. Use the `xlink` namespace for the `href` attribute
3. Install [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/). If it is in `PATH`, imagick will pick it up to render the file. Do not use librsvg, it will fail.
4. Do not include the invalid `<img>` tag from the HTML namespace.

This file was rendering for me in Inkscape, but not with `rsvg-convert`:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="800" height="800" viewBox="0 0 800 800">
  <image x='322' y='402' preserveAspectRatio='none' xlink:href='data:image/png;base64,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'></image>
</svg>
```

As for ImageMagick, I was running into problems because librsvg was installed in parallel, and despite what the [documentation](https://imagemagick.org/script/formats.php#supported) says, was prefered. But as in the optimal case the conversion is delegated to Inkscape anyway, you can use it directly in CLI mode:

```
inkscape -o image.png .\test.svg
```